# How to filter out columns that have negative values and save the rest of the columns in a new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to filter out from a data frame all variables that have negative values. I used this line of code (below) to get the names of the columns but how can I save the positive columns with their data as a new data frame

```
dat <- read.table(text = " value jobs  chairs    tables     lamps  vases
                                -1     0        0        0         7  9
                                 2     0        0        1         1  6 
                                -3     0        1        0         3  5 
                                 4     0        1        1         7  8 
                                -5     1        0        0         5  4
                                -6     1        0        1         1  3 
                                 7     1        1        0         0  7
                                 8     1        1        1         6  6
                                 9     0        0        0         8  9  ", header = TRUE) 

names(dat)[sapply(dat, function(x) min(x))>=0]
[1] "value"  "jobs"   "chairs" "tables" "lamps"  "vases"
```

Comment: What's your desired output? Does `dat[, colSums(dat < 0) == 0]` works for you? Or `dat[, colSums(sapply(dat, "<", 0)) == 0]` in order to avoid to `matrix` conversion

Comment: Yes,Thanks  @David Arenburg

Comment: @DavidArenburg what do you mean 'in order to avoid `matrix` conversion'? outputs of both of your suggestions are `data.frames`.

Comment: @stasg see `class(dat < 0)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg but `class(sapply(dat, "<", 0))` is also `matrix`

Comment: @stasg yes, because `sapply` *returns* a `matrix` but it doesn't *convert* the data set itself to a `matrix` because it operates per vector instead over the whole data set.

Comment: @DavidArenburg okay, i see now. so, i guess, one would care about this only for very large datasets

Comment: @stasg yes, I always think of big data sets, otherwise we could just close it off with `apply(data, 1, whatever)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Any idea why your solutions could give me the following error: `Error in [.data.frame(df, , colSums(df< 0) == 0) : 
  undefined columns selected`?

Comment: @TomKisters don't know. That doesn't sound right. Does this solution works on the data provided by the OP?

Comment: It does.. I'm guessing non-numerical values (in one or two variables) might be the reason for the column not being created right? I used `colSums(!is.na(dat))` before which worked fine. But I guess with `<` it does not work so well.. Is it possible to do something like: `dat[, if(is.numeric(colSums(dat < 0) == 0) else NA]` to prevent this?

Comment: I guess it would be much better to subset the variables with non-numerical values before and add them back later right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the names you retrieved  to subset your data frame:

```
myNames<-names(dat)[sapply(dat, function(x) min(x))>=0]
dat[,myNames]
```

Edit: if you don't need these names for later use:

```
dat[,sapply(dat, min)>=0]
```

Comment: *You Could* use I would say. There are many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 1):

or

```
dat[, sapply(dat, FUN = function(x) all(x >= 0))]
```

or

```
dat[, sapply(dat, FUN = function(x) !any(x < 0))]
```